# Constructor revolts? What's happening?

Tags: c++, constructor

I've got an assignment, some demands were made such as making an abstract baseclass for two types of questions which will be subclasses, and another demand is that all three classes have to have two constructors and that only the destructors may be empty.

So I did this in the .cpp of Question(baseclass):

```
Question::Question(string question)
{
    this->question = question;
}

Question::Question()
{
    this->question = "N/A";
}
```

And in one of the subclasses called "*MultipleAnswerQuestion*" I try doing this:

```
MultipleAnswerQuestion::MultipleAnswerQuestion(string question, string alternatives[], 
int alternativeAmount, int correctAnswer):Question(question)
{
    for(int i=0; i<alternativeAmount; i++){ 
        this->alternatives[i] = alternatives[i]; //string
    }
    this->alternativeAmount = alternativeAmount; //int
    this->correctAnswer = correctAnswer; //int
}

MultipleAnswerQuestion::MultipleAnswerQuestion()
{
    for(int i=0; i<alternativeAmount; i++){ 
        this->alternatives[i] = ""; //string
    }
    this->alternativeAmount = NULL; //int
    this->correctAnswer = NULL; //int
}
```

And an error comes up about the bottom constructor of MultipleAnswerQuestion, saying:
"*IntelliSense: class "Question" has more than one default constructor*"

What's wrong?? How do I solve this?

Filling out the constructors and having two of them is a demand, so I can't just remove one.

**EDIT**
Class declarations:

```
class Question
{
    public:
        Question();
        Question(string question = "N/A");
        virtual ~Question();

        void setQuestion(const string &question);
        string getQuestion() const;

        void print() const;

        virtual void printSpec() const=0;

    private:
        string question;

};
```

And MultipleAnswerQuestion:

```
const int MAX = 6;
class MultipleAnswerQuestion :
    public Question
{
    public:
        MultipleAnswerQuestion();
        MultipleAnswerQuestion(string question, string alternatives[], int alternativeAmount, int correctAnswer);
        virtual ~MultipleAnswerQuestion();

        void printSpec() const;
        void setCorrectAnswer(int correctAnswer);
        void setAlternative(int alternativeNr, string alternative);

    private:
        int correctAnswer;
        string alternatives[MAX];
        int alternativeAmount;
};
```

Comment: Try actual compilation as a part of [MCVE], if nothing else.

Comment: Show us the *declaration* of `Question`, because that's where the problem is. The .cpp code is useless without it.

Comment: Well, one thing I see that's wrong here is a reliance on using crutches supplied by an overbloated IDE as a substitute for learning and understanding C++ fundamentals. Makes me wonder how I ever managed to learn C++ using nothing more than a plain text editor, and a command-line compiler.

Comment: @Mark Ransom I've put it up.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Meaning?

Comment: @GhostofBillGates By the way, it's better to pass string by reference, to prevent unexpected coping, e.g. change `Question(string question)` to  `Question(const string& question)`

Comment: I meant exactly what I wrote.

Comment: @Nikita I do otherwise, but another demand is "every parameter that can be const should be made const".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Don't know what you mean, I typed every character myself. And even if I wouldn't have, I don't see why that's a problem.

Comment: @Nikita A bit irrelevant at this point perhaps since I've got my answer, but I forgot to add; I will make the others const too wherever it doesn't mess things up, just that I'm not even halfway into the assignment yet.

Comment: @GhostofBillGates -- What SamVarshachik means is that you totally missed the fundamentals (like ambiguity in the constructor functions), and instead you are using a tool to point out these things.  Also, the example that would have proven that there is an issue is with multiple declarations of the same constructor is simply: `Question q;`  So which constructor would have been called?  The one with actually no arguments, or the one that can be called with no arguments?  See the ambiguity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two constructors, one default and one taking a string. However you've declared the string constructor with a default parameter, so if you try to construct one without any parameters there are *two* that could potentially be used. The compiler complains because it can't use both and doesn't have a rule to pick one over the other.

Either delete the default constructor, or remove the default on the string parameter.

Comment: Ohh, right. Don't now how I could've missed that. Thanks for the concise & precise answer though!